# How to use Calendar Provider with Android emulator

Tags: android, calendar

I intend to use the emulator to test the new [Calendar Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html).
I created a virtual device from Google API image and added a Google account to the calendar. 
I started the Calendar application and it said no Google account was added or nothing was synched.

[image: calendar]

In the account settings I used Sync now, but it was unable to sync.

I checked [this article](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2716936?hl=en) and it says that no longer possible to use Google Sync instead I should use some new protocol but no further instructions were provided.

In 2010 they [suggested](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/using-a-google-account-in-the-emulator/) to add my Google account as an Exchange account and simply change the server name. It is rejected, so I am stuck.

[image]

[image]

Can you tell me how I could test the Calendar Provider with an emulator?

Comment: I hate when I ask something that is most likely inextricable :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple: **it is impossible**.

Comment: Maybe a link that supports your claim could help!

Comment: You can see them in the initial post.